# Status field in Highlights Panel not showing in certain profile

Tags: lightning, case, ui, highlights-panel

I hope someone can help me coz I'm stuck. So I have a page layout and lightning page which is being shared my multiple profiles. However, it seems like the status in Highlights Panel of my Lightning Page is not showing up in this certain profile but it's showing in another profile even though they are sharing the same page layout and Lightning Page.

[image]

[image]

Also the profile has access to the field.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you say that one user with a certain profile sees the field in the highlight panel and the second one with a different profile doesn't, I suggest you check the access to this field for the second profile.
Probably this profile has no access to field in the field-level security for this object.

Comment: Did that. The status field is showing in fields layout of the profile but not in highlighs panel

Comment: Can you try to clear cache of the browser or something like that? As I read, it's the often problem with the Highlight Panel that changes are not reflected quickly.

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdiTvUAJ/compact-layout-field-changes-not-reflected-in-lightning-highlights-panel

Comment: You can check if the compact layout in Setup --> Object Manager --> Service Request (Your object) --> Compact Layouts, is assigned for proper record type

Comment: Do you mean in Compact Layout Assignment?

Comment: Yes, and you should assign Compact Layout which include your fields you want to show in Highlight Panel, to certain Record Type for which you Lightning Page is assigned

Comment: I created a new compact layout and assign it by order. It seems to work though.  But I still don't understand why it work because the profile is the problem and what we did is assign by record type. I only have 4 fields on it.

Comment: @SaberM - `Case.Status` values are associated with `Support Processes` that in turn are related to recordtypes